# How do I defeat this C++ Vector Sorting error? 

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Here's the problem code I'm attempting to compile:

```
bool TeamMatcher::simpleComparator(Student first, Student second){
  return (first.numberOfHrsAvailable < second.numberOfHrsAvailable);
}

void TeamMatcher::sortRosters(){
  sort(rosterExcellent.begin(), rosterExcellent.end(), simpleComparator);
  sort(rosterGood.begin(), rosterGood.end(), simpleComparator);
  sort(rosterOK.begin(), rosterOK.end(), simpleComparator);
  sort(rosterPoor.begin(), rosterPoor.end(), simpleComparator);
  sort(rosterNoSay.begin(), rosterNoSay.end(), simpleComparator);
}
```

Then here's the error I'm getting:

```
TeamMatcher.C: In member function ‘void TeamMatcher::sortRosters()’:
TeamMatcher.C:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2852: note: candidates are: void std::sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, _Compare = bool (TeamMatcher::*)(Student, Student)]
```

It repeats this error for the four remaining sorts. I don't understand, I'm basically copy/pasting this solution from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you add the using namespace directive `using namespace std;` to your file, if not you need to quality the name of the algorithm with `std` namespace as `std::sort`.

Comment: I did, at least in my .h file that I imported into this .C file. That's still good right?

Comment: @Als - you can see from the compiler output that it's already looking at `std::sort` as a candidate, which means that's not the problem.

Comment: It is not a problem then but its not all good, **Do not add using directives in header files** it is a bad practice. It imports all the symbols from that namespace in to Translation Unit where you include your header.This leads to symbol name pollution,trust me `std` namespace has a lot of stuff that you wont need.Also, this might result in longer compilation times.Use **using declarations** instead in your source cpp file.

Comment: @tzaman: I posted the comment before Joachim edited the Q to make the error readable.It was a first hunch without seeing the unreadable error message.This is sometimes known as **psychic debugging** of problems.Also, Since it was only a guess I posted it as a comment and not answer.

Comment: @Als - fair enough :) I already upvoted your comment about using directives, namespace pollution == bad.

Comment: Alright cool, no using directives in header files, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare your `simpleComparator` as a `static` method, otherwise it won't fit the type expected by `std::sort`.

To be perfectly correct, you should also then pass it as `TeamMatcher::simpleComparator`, see [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1) for details.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much! This fixed it! Way to win at life

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead for your comparison function:

```
bool simpleComparator(const Student& first, const Student& second){
    return (first.numberOfHrsAvailable < second.numberOfHrsAvailable);
}
```

Note that the comparison function is not a member of your TeamMember class, and passing const references in prevents needless copying.

You can take one step further and define a comparison method for Students

```
bool Student::operator<(const Student& first, const Student& second)
{
    return (first.numberOfHrsAvailable < second.numberOfHrsAvailable);
}
```

Now you can just call sort on your students and it'll have a comparison method to use:

```
std::sort(studentIter.begin(), studentIter.end());
```

However in this case I recommend the first approach, unless you always want to compare Students by the number of hours available. For instance, this may be confusing to another programmer:

```
if ( studentA < studentB )
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

It may be confusing because it's not readily apparent how you would compare two students (GPA, attendances, hours available, height, IQ, whatever...)